# Seeking Advice for Upgrading 2020 Surly Krampus Groupset

Tags: groupsets, bikepacking

I’m looking to gear up for some bikepacking with my [Surly Krampus](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/krampus)  (2020 model) for early next year. I’ll mostly be doing gravel/dirt, Forest Service Roads, fire roads, singletrack, and the occasional paved along this route. My biggest concern is the hilly sections and finding the granny gears to help me out. I’m in the process of upgrading the groupset and prefer mechanical shifters over electronic. I’ve narrowed down my options to SRAM GX Eagle (12-speed) and Shimano XT 12-speed after some research. Both seem promising, but I value real-world experiences and recommendations from the community.

Has anyone used SRAM GX Eagle or Shimano XT 12-speed for a similar bikepacking setup? I’m particularly interested in your insights on durability, ease of maintenance, and overall performance. Any advice you can offer would be invaluable.

Additionally, I’m curious if either of these options justifies the cost over Shimano SLX 12-speed, SRAM NX Eagle (12-speed), or Shimano Deore 12-speed. Your comparisons between these groupsets would greatly assist my decision-making process.

Would it be just as effective to upgrade the crankset, wheeler, or hubs??

I am at a complete loss here as a lot of this is above my pay grade. Thank you in advance for your expertise and assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  This may get flagged as product recommendations can be quite subjective.

Comment: To begin to answer this, one would need to know more about what is and isn't working for you currently. What's your current low gear and how is it working under comparable circumstances?

Comment: Based on the current spec, this bike was stock with an 11-51 tooth 12 speed cassette, and a Shimano Deore XT RD-M8100 rear derailleur.   Does that match your bike?   I count 32 teeth on the chainring in the photo, does that match your bike?   Are you trying to find a gearing that will allow you to ride up every climb and not walk it?